# Sign in with google prevents the user to sign in again with different account - iOS

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm using google authentication to sign in with firebase.
The authentication process works well and I'm able to create the credentials and authenticate.

My problem is when, after signing out from firebase and google, the user tries to sign in using google again. At this point google will automatically authenticate with the account used previously. 
I tried both sign-out and disconnect option from google api but the result is the same.

I partially found what my problem was, here steps to reproduce:

1. Not signed in with google in app and not signed-in in safari on the device with a google account
2. Sign in with the application using a google account
3. Now I am signed-in in app AND in safari as well with the same account
4. When I sign-out from the application, safari is still authenticated with this user
5. I'm not able to see the account choice in app until I sign-out the google account from safari on the device

This problem doesn't show up if safari (point 1) was already signed-in with a different google account. In this case I will always have a choice between the two accounts in app.

Is there a way to sign out from the app and always shows the account choice when signing in with google again?

Comment: What SDK do you use to sign in in app?

Comment: I have the exact same problem! Using pod 'GoogleSignIn', '= 4.1.2'. This appears to have started recently. I tried to find a suitable Google bug tracker, but there doesn't seem to be one for the sign in sdk.

Comment: I wrote a bug report in the googlesamples/google-services repo on GitHub https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/357

Comment: Any fix on this issue? facing the same issue.

Comment: Working fine now.

Comment: Still not working for me. @abhi1992 What did you do to make it work?

Comment: Seems like it is related to setting of `[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].serverClientID = XXXXXX`. When I remove that setting, the select dialogue appear.

Comment: I did nothing. It is working fine now. But I did re-create the project in firebase console as I had to change the bundle ID for some reason. Just create a dummy app and test.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Authentication URI parameters. One of them is "prompt" which could have a "select_account" value. It helped me to resolve the same issue for Auth0-service Google integration. Maybe could be useful for your issue if the SDK allows setting parameters for sign in.
See docs here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authenticationuriparameters